# Postfix odd configuration

Tags: server, email, postfix

The Ubuntu 14.04's postfix (installed from mail-stack-delivery meta package) configuration file, main.cf, comes with an odd configuration directive:

<s>smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination</s>

<s>Based on how those [restrictions work](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix_restrictions), I can't understand what reject_unknown_sender_domain restriction is doing under smtpd_recipient_restrictions.</s>

<s>reject_unknown_sender_domain restriction also is placed under smtpd_sender_restrictions, where, I think, it's make more sense:</s>

<s>smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain</s>

<s>How does a sender restriction under smtpd_recipient_restrictions makes any sense?</s>

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
```

Placing **reject_unknown_sender_domain** under either smtpd_recipient_restrictions or smtpd_sender_restrictions has the same effect.. but why mail-stack-delivery main.cf file has it under both?

Comment: The documentation you linked is not very good, I suggest you read this one: http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html

Comment: @fkraiem, Ok. I understand now that placing reject_unknown_sender_domain under either smtpd_recipient_restrictions or smtpd_sender_restrictions has the same effect.. but why ubuntu's default main.cf file has it under both?

Answer (score 0):

Think from the perspective of the server, not the client.

The Postfix server receives and processes email for potential recipients on your server and therefore needs to apply checks to that to filter spam, including determining whether or not the received email comes from a known domain. If it doesn't, it's a safe bet it's spam and you can reject it.

To apply the same restriction when your Postfix server sends email for your users would simply mean it checks to see if YOUR domain exists or not, which of course it does, so it's a moot check.

Comment: But smtpd_sender_restrictions is not applied when postfix send email.. It's when it receives, and look at the MAIL FROM: part of the message..